# what is the difference between kendo.data.dataSource object and object for dataSource field of kendo widget

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, kendo-datasource

I've studied kendo UI framework.
I found out that dataSource field for kendo widget could be object, array or kendo.data.dataSource object.
is there any differences of process among these for making Kendo widget?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no difference on initializing a widget using Object, Array or DataSource in the `dataSource` option. The widget will create a dataSource internally anyway.

From the [docs](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-dataSource):

> If the dataSource option is set to a JavaScript object or array the widget will initialize a new kendo.data.DataSource instance using that value as data source configuration.
>
> If the dataSource option is an existing kendo.data.DataSource instance the widget will use that instance and will not initialize a new one